# Break the line in a line plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a pyplot plot in Python, and the points are joined by lines.

I would like to break the line half way though the plot.

Is this possible?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Draw the two halves of the line separately over the points? Perhaps you can sketch what you (more or less) exactly want?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. For example if I have 10 data points, I want to join 1-5 with a line and then join 6-10 with a line.

Comment: I think @Evert gave you the solution. Plot points 1-5. Hold the plot. Plot points 6-10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as pl
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 5, 10)
y = np.sin(x)
pl.plot(x, y, 'o')
pl.plot(x[:5], y[:5], 'g-')
pl.plot(x[5:], y[5:], 'g-')
pl.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

From my experiences, the best way to work with points is [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/).
its eazy to use.

maybe you should add you code so i can understand how you store your data.

GoodLuck!

Answer (score 1):

Plot 1-5 as one series and 6-10 as a separate one!  Pyplot, (any plotting system), should except more than one set of data for separate lines.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting your data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
break_at = 0
x = np.linspace(-1,1,100)
i1 = np.where(x>break_at)
i2 = np.where(x<break_at)
plt.plot(x[i1],x[i1]**2)
plt.plot(x[i2],x[i2]**2)
plt.show()
```